# What format is this 128 bit AES key specified with in this example?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptoapi

I am referencing [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hasherezade/2860d94910c5c5fb776edadf57f0bef6) available online.

It's using a hard-coded 128 bit AES key to encrypt/decrypt data. The key is hard-coded in this format:

```
wchar_t default_key[] = L"3igcZhRdWq96m3GUmTAiv9";
```

How is a 128 bit AES key specified in this format? And how would I, for example, specify/convert an AES 256 key in raw hex form (like shown below) in the same format:

> 5DD34BE0C9C344833C91E20D247C3B2988340A034C9719C7C291EC2F781F8133

Note that all keys shown here are just examples and not used to encrypt any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

It is *likely* that the hardcoded key is a base64 encoded 128-bit key without padding.  But it is also possible that it is arbitrary UTF8 that is padded to become the 128 bit key.  I'd put my money on the prior, though.

If you'd like to take your provided key in hex and use that instead, you just need to convert from hex to base64.

I expect then that your key would look like this:

`XdNL4MnDRIM8keINJHw7KYg0CgNMlxnHwpHsL3gfgTM`

You may need to make further adjustments to the gist you have to ensure it knows you are using a 256-bit key now.